# How to show alert dialog in a running thread?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, game-loop

I'm developing an Android Game.In this game, There are tracks on which trains run. This is running thread. I want to show an alert dialog when there is a collision between. when I'm applying alert dialog showing error can't create handler inside thread that has not called `looper.prepare()`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must need to create `AlertDialog` inside UI thread else it will never work. If you are in different thread use `MessageHandler` or can use `runOnUiThread`(using runnable) to create your dialog inside.

Answer (score 15):

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your dialog code.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use Handlers to do this work.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Your UI updates here
    }
});
```

Comment: you need initializate variable Handler mHandler= new Handler();

Answer (score 6):

You can create an handler in Activity Class, and can invoke sendMessage to that handler object. Write code to display alert in handleMessage method of Handler, for Example:

Activity Class

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
       //Display Alert
    }
};

//Thread

Thread thread= new Thread()
{
    public void run()
    {
         //Logic
         MHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to show your dialog on UI thread like below

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                // Your dialog code.
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, with check App is visible

```
Activity currentActivity = MainClassApp.getCurrentActivity();
boolean isAppVisible = currentActivity != null;

if (isAppVisible) {
    currentActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> 
    // Your Dialog Code 
}
```