# Android run on uithread - i want to open dialog boxes at a intreval of 5 secs can anyone help me out of this

Tags: android

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = MainActivity.restime;
        final List<String> ls = UStats.printCurrentUsageStatuspop(ServiceTest.this, "Daily");

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                ServiceTest.this);

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, close
                        // current activity
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }



};
```

throws error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
   at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
   at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:119)
   at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:168)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.<init>(AppCompatDialog.java:43)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:95)
   at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:927)
   at com.example.admin.digitaltime.ServiceTest$1.run(ServiceTest.java:100)
   at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. That's how you should format your question, before posting : your code parts, stacktrace should be in code blocks, such blocks should be readable, without unnecessary litter like commented code parts

Comment: Your question is duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400620/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-a-running-thread). Take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about these methods 
1. post(Runnable runnable)
2. postDelayed(Runnable runnable, long delaytime)

Both of them are methods of View class so you can call them on any view like button, textview etc.

I am not that clear from your question but I think you might need second method to get delay of some time on UI thread.