# xamarin android app crashes on thread start

Tags: android, xamarin

am making an android app soo as soon as i run a thread

```
    Thread server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverHandle));
    server.Start();
```

the app crashes without any error messages and it only happens on release mode , on debugging everything seems to be ok

it only works if serverHandle is empty but if anything is inside like this

```
    private void serverHandle()
    {

    AlertDialog.Builder  alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.SetMessage("test");
        alert.Show();
    }
```

it stops working any help why is this ?

Comment: I created an empty project with the codes , created android package and installed it on my android device and run. There is no crush or error. Please make sure you sideloaded the app by steps of [Sign the Android Application](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/) .

Comment: the coder runs as long as serverHandle is empty once i put anything inside like this 

private void serverHandle()
        {
             AlertDialog.Builder  aler = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            aler.SetMessage("test");
            aler.Show();
        }


it simply stops working

Comment: Could you please post the codes of `serverhandle`, or is it just an empty function?

Comment: i edited the question , it's working only when the function is empty anything inside and it crushes

Answer (score 0):

`AlertDialog` can only be used in UI Thread. Please refer to [How to show alert dialog in a running thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400620/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-a-running-thread).

So, if you want the codes to work, you can modify it like this:

```
Thread server = new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=> {
            //run the AlertDialog in the UI Thread.
            RunOnUiThread(() => {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetMessage("test");
                alert.Show();
            });
        }));
server.Start();
```

Comment: does everything needs to be running on UI thread , cause if i put this

        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1000);
         listener.Start();

it crushes again

Comment: I don't think it's the same reason as `AlertDialog` that crush the app. Please try modifying the port number. Port 1000 is probably and easily possessed by other application.

Comment: used all kind of port numbers none of em worked and in debug mode it works fine don't know why